# android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1 directory

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-components, aar, android-architecture-lifecycle

I am trying to add lifecycle:extensions to my project but it shows the err

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1.
```

None of solutions provided in the web doesn't helped me. My question is not about how resolve the error.
After checking sdk different directories, I noticed that there is a directory in the following directory with number of Java classes:

```
<SDK_HOME>\sources\android-27\android\arch\lifecycle
```

My question is that after successful downloading "extensions-1.1.1.aar" from a repository, in which directory it (aar file) would be saved? And which files would be downloaded with the .aar file (such as .pom/.pom.sha1 ...)? Thanks.

Comment: Update your grade properties, hopefully, it will work.

Comment: Would you please share build.gradle file with your question?

Answer (score 0):

This artifact was published to `mavenCentral()`, most likely to `google()`, too.

```
dependencies {

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/android.arch.lifecycle/extensions
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
}
```

`SDK_HOME` is something very else. if wanting to load from a local repository, use `mavenLocal()` - but this only works once having added the required artifacts into it - else it will not find them; this only makes sense, when working offline.